# jquery find div not working offline but working online

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

i have this   [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kd6Y4/1/)

which is getting div from a different page on same site and display it 
the problem is its working perfectly online like this direct link 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/kd6Y4/1/show/
search for hand or and in both

but its not working offline 
 i placed both files in same directory 
src to the jquery file is correct downloaded jquery file and placed in correct directory 
its not working offline 
please help i need to use this in a android environment in webview both files will be there offline 
 this is the code i am using with jquery 1.10.1

```
   $("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var results = $("#resultContainer");
var text = $("#search").val();
results.empty();
$.get("url here", function (data) {
    var els = $(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")").appendTo(results);
    els.find('a').attr('href', function (_, href) {
        return 'url here/#' + $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    })
});
 });
```

[this error is coming how to resolve]

XML Http request cannot load file no "access control allow origin" header is present on the requested resource origin stuff is therefore not allowed access

how to resolve this error i check this in chrome its working online but not offline sorry am newbie to jquery

Comment: Please try code "hello world!" with alert() to make sure your jquery is working. $(function(){ alert('hello world!'); });

Comment: checked its working displaying Hello world alert when i open the page

Comment: but this code is not working while its working online

Comment: what is #searchForm element? is it a button? or the form?

Comment: is code wrapped in a `ready` handler? fiddle does that for you so can be ignored there

Comment: this error is coming how to resolve]

XML Http request cannot load file no "access control allow origin" header is present on the requested resource origin stuff is therefore not allowed access

Answer (score 0):

I think the $.get is based on HTTP request and response, so it doesn't work for getting local files.

Let's say the page runs the javascript is Page1, and another page is Page2, you can try this:
get Page2 html by java in antroid environment and pass it to webview, so that you can get Page2 html in Page1, then you can use $(html) to rebuild Page2 into a jQuery object, and you can find what you want from this object.

Hope it helps.